# Sprintf is changing the values of an array

Tags: c

I'm having and error using sprintf. I want to use sprintf to create a new name file. The names should be 000.jpg, 001.jpg, 002.jpg etc. After use fread() I'm storing the values in an array name buffer[] The problem is after I use sprintf() the values of my array changes. I do not understand Why???

Before of sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", pictures) the first four values in hex of buffer[] are 0xff,0xd8,0xff,0xe0 but after sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", pictures) the first four values of buffer[] changes to 0x30,0x30,0x2e,0x6a. I can not understand why? :(

Thanks for your help

```
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char name[1];
    int pictures = 0;
    char *infile = argv[1];
    FILE *card = fopen(infile, "r");
    FILE *imagen = NULL;
    
    while (pictures < 50)
    {
        fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card);
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {               
                
            if (pictures > 0)
            {
                fclose(imagen);
            }
            sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", pictures);
            imagen = fopen(name, "w");
            pictures ++;
            
        }
        if (pictures > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, imagen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `char name[1];` is not long enough to store your filenames. You're overflowing the buffer. The overwritten bytes you're seeing, 0x30,0x30,0x2e,0x6a are "00.j".

Comment: You rigth that was the problem. Just to be clare. The overflow of name[] was using space of my array buffer[] to store the remaining values? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, but it could instead have used a different place or started playing music by Chopin. In theory, that is. It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means _anything_ can happen (including deleting your entire harddrive which actually did happen to me once due to an unfortunate combination of circumstances, so be aware of such issues in your code - in less drastic circumstances they still can cause crashes and possible user data loss and are a common source of security vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
char name[1];
```

`name` is only big enough to hold a single character.  So when you pass it to `sprintf`, the function writes past the bounds of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This array needs to be at least 8 characters wide: 3 for the numeric part 4 for the extension, and 1 for the null terminating byte.

```
char name[8];
```

Comment: can I use instead char *name = NULL; ??

Comment: @David If you did, you would then need to call `malloc` to allocate memory for `name` to point to.

Comment: (and `free` the memory afterwards!)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a buffer overflow issue.

You have defined `name` as `char[1]`, i.e. a string that is *one* byte long (which can then only ever be an empty string, since the string terminator would take up that byte), yet you are writing 8 bytes into it (e.g. `000.jpg␀` including the string terminator)!

So, the remaining 7 bytes get written beyond your buffer `name` into whatever happens to be located after it in memory, which seems to be your `buffer` array in that case. (Note that the "hex values `0x30,0x30,0x2e,0x6a`" are actually `00.j` if you look at their character representations. The remaining part of your string, `pg␀`, probably ended up elsewhere in your variables and you just didn't find it yet, or worse it may have corrupted your stack.)

You would have to dimension your string accordingly (as `char[8]` in your case), and additionally it'd be best to use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) instead of `sprintf` where you can pass your max. string length so it will not overflow even if you pass a buffer that is too short (as long as you pass the true buffer length too).

Answer (score 0):

`char name[1];` has only space for the terminating nul character.

it has to be much longer (max number of the filename characters + 1).

Example:

```
#define MAXFILENAME 20

char name[MAXFILENAME + 1];
```